Retrieve the names of Accounts along with the total amount of all their associated Opportunities
I am trying below.
Retrieve the names of Accounts along with the total amount of all their associated Opportunities.
But I want the query to be on Account and not on Opportunity. Please let me know. Thanks.

Sounds like a job for a rollup summary field to me. Is there a reason why you can't use that standard feature?

What have you tried so far?

Child-to-parent : select count(id), max(amount),accountid from opportunity group by accountid. This works fine, but I am trying to write query on Account for this usecase.

There is no built-in rollup functionality of child records when you do a SOQL query at the parent level.
You have two options:
Run an aggregate query on Opportunity and group by the account Name.
Or you can use a rollup tool like the open-source Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries or Rollup Helper to rollup opps to summary fields on the Account record, then run your query on those account fields.
